# Passing a parameter into pytest file and running it in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, oop, jupyter-notebook, pytest

Assume I have the following pytest based code inside a file called test_treshold.py:

```
import pandas as pd 

class TestSomething:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame, treshold: int):
        self.avg_scores = df
        self.treshold= treshold

    def test_metrics(self):
        
        metric_value = self.df[self.df['metric'] == 'specified_metric']['value']
        treshold = self.treshold
        assert metric_value <= treshold
```

This is one of the many tests this class has.

The dataframe in question that's passed to the class comes along inside a jupyter notebook script. Eventually, I want a way to pass this dataframe into the constructor object alongside a treshold and run the pytest.

In my code I'm already on the stage of:

```
from test_treshold import TestSomething


df = SomeDf()
treshold = 0.5

test_obj = TestSomething(df, treshold)
```

But I don't have a way to properly call the pytest on the module in question. Is there anyway I can do what I wish to do, or there may be a work around this?

The important thing would be to keep the original pytest test_treshold.py file.